# subseting data set based on date calculations

Tags: r

I have this data frame. I would like to create another data frame from this which will include Trade_Date, Trades and Rejected. The rejected field needs to have the values from Closing_Date which will have to meet this criteria - Trade_Date + 1 day.

x

```
Trade_Date   Trades   Closing_Date   Rejected
9/16/2011   4126528     9/16/2011   15
9/19/2011   2565282     9/17/2011   33
9/20/2011   2953963     9/20/2011   30
9/21/2011   3255800     9/21/2011   6
9/22/2011   2862185     9/22/2011   21
9/23/2011   2405590     9/23/2011   30
9/26/2011   3196284     9/24/2011   30
9/27/2011   3761367     9/27/2011   15
9/28/2011   3198177     9/28/2011   9
9/29/2011   3255345     9/29/2011   6
9/30/2011   3810356     9/30/2011   12
10/3/2011   3817093     10/1/2011   21
```

for example, my next df will need to be like this:

```
Trade_Date      Trades    Rejected
9/16/2011       4126528   33
9/19/2011       2565282   30
9/20/2011       2953963   6
```

etc

Since there are many many rows, I need to do this programatically. Can any help?

Comment: Questions like this have been asked and answered dozens of times here. Please look for [r] as well 'xts' and 'zoo' as those packages help a great deal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the rows in your example data frame meet the criteria you specify, so I will alter it slightly to demonstrate a simple way of doing this:

```
#Read the data in
dat <- read.table(text = "Trade_Date   Trades   Closing_Date   Rejected
 9/16/2011   4126528     9/16/2011   15
 9/19/2011   2565282     9/17/2011   33
 9/20/2011   2953963     9/20/2011   30
 9/21/2011   3255800     9/21/2011   6
 9/22/2011   2862185     9/22/2011   21
 9/23/2011   2405590     9/23/2011   30
 9/26/2011   3196284     9/24/2011   30
 9/27/2011   3761367     9/27/2011   15
 9/28/2011   3198177     9/28/2011   9
 9/29/2011   3255345     9/29/2011   6
 9/30/2011   3810356     9/30/2011   12
 10/3/2011   3817093     10/1/2011   21",sep = "",header = TRUE)

#Convert to date
dat$Trade_Date <- as.Date(dat$Trade_Date,"%m/%d/%Y")
dat$Closing_Date <- as.Date(dat$Closing_Date,"%m/%d/%Y")

#Alter some rows to meet your criteria
dat$Closing_Date[1:3] <- dat$Trade_Date[1:3] + 1

#Then we can simply subset the data
> dat[dat$Closing_Date == dat$Trade_Date+1,]
  Trade_Date  Trades Closing_Date Rejected
1 2011-09-16 4126528   2011-09-17       15
2 2011-09-19 2565282   2011-09-20       33
3 2011-09-20 2953963   2011-09-21       30
```